# Google Analytics Exit Pages report

Tags: report, analytics, exit

I'm using Google Analytics to quantify exit rates from website pages and am confused by the use of the "page" dimension, rather than the "exit page" dimension, as the primary dimension within the Behaviour/Site Content/Exit Pages report.

Having spoken with Google Analytics people about this question I am no closer to an answer, they claim I should include "exit page" as the secondary dimension within the report, having to include an additional dimension within a standard analytics report seems illogical to me.

Any help explaining why the report has been configured this way will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think of "exit pages" in these two ways:

1. What are the number of exits that occur on a page?
2. What are the pages that people exit on (when some condition exists)*?

The 1) first is easily answered on the Exit Page report you mention. You sort by exits descending and that shows you the number of exits that occur on the page. You make a decision about the performance of the page based on whether you think that exit rate aligns with what you would expect people to do on the site.  For example,  if the **/transaction/success.html** page has a high exit rate... probably not a big deal.  If the **/search/results.html** has a high exit rate then you've got a problem.

The 2) second is something that you do at a high level of analysis. You analyze the exit based on some condition.  It doesn't make sense to do this in the "**Exit Page**" report... Rather,  you should go first go to something like **Landing Page** report and then add "**Exit Page**" as a secondary dimension.  This narrative is more informative, as it shows you where people started, and where they ended, in ranking order.

Make more sense?